# Which variable stores the root node of a C GENERIC AST in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to write a plugin for gcc 4.5 that will perform some analysis on the AST ([GENERIC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html#GENERIC) representation) just after parsing is complete. My source language is C and the plugin will be written in C as well. There are a few posts [here](http://codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/05/03/parsing-cxx-with-gcc-plugin-part-1/) that explain how to do such a thing for C++. Both the GENERIC documentation and the previous link state that the variable `global_namespace` stores the root node of a C++ GENERIC AST. Which variable stores the root node of a C GENERIC AST?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously no such things as namespaces for C but the concept of *scopes* does exist however. You can access the englobing scope of where you are (that depends on which event your plugin is called by GCC) through the function `pop_scope()` defined in `c-tree.h`. This returns a `tree` which is composed of a `block`. You can access all the declarations of this block, i.e. the symbols (variables, functions, etc.) declared at this scope through the macro `BLOCK_VARS` which provides you with a `tree` of decl-nodes.

If you neeed access to a function body, remember than you can always access it from the function definition through the macro `DECL_SAVED_TREE(node)`, `node` being your `FUNCTION_DECL` node. This is valid only if the definition is in the same file and already built, again, it depends on where you hook your plugin.

Disclaimer: this is valid for GCC 4.8 and the interface is subject to frequent changes. As of GCC 4.9, the plugin interface is partially written in C++.